# How can I input Unicode characters in Kate and Konsole on Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, unicode

In Kubuntu 18.04 Konsole or Kate applications, I cannot get special characters by enter a Unicode, such as 0x1234 to display 'ሴ'. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> combo key does not work on those applications, but it works on gnome-terminal and other gtk3 applications. How can I type such Unicode characters in Kate or Konsole?

Comment: Re. konsole, `echo -e 'u1234'` will generate the symbol you want in the terminal command line.

Comment: @dk-bose Nice solution, but the required backslash in `echo -e '\u1234'` before the "u" character was not visible in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

As you observed, many Unicode characters can be entered in gtk-based applications using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by a specific alphanumeric string but such an approach doesn't work at all in Kate or Konsole. This has been the case [since 2005 at least](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103788).

One has to instead [use a Compose key](https://superuser.com/questions/74763/how-to-type-unicode-characters-in-kde). To do that, open **System Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced**. In there, scroll down to **Position of Compose Key**. Expand that by clicking on **>** and choose a convenient key. I chose **Caps Lock**. Be aware that you'll no longer have the normal function of that key or any other key you set as the **Compose** key:

[image: Compose Key]

Once that is done, create an empty (hidden) file called `.XCompose` in your home folder and add the following line:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"
```

Save the file. Then, examine `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` for suitable code as shown in an answer to [How to type unicode characters in KDE?](https://superuser.com/a/78724/462117).

Here's a few examples copied from the answer:

- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>   →   Č
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>´</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>   →   É
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>_</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>   →   ū
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>   →   î

If you still find there are symbols that you can't generate in Kate or Konsole such as the one in your question, ሴ,  a very, very, ugly workaround is to make a text file in a gtk text editor, generate all the missing symbols there, save the file and then copy/paste as needed into Kate or Konsole whenever you need them. That works just fine and saves the trouble of memorising a list of Unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I will try to use this method. Look forward to solving this problem in a more convenient way in the new version. Wish you a happy life and work.

Comment: @dk-bose 's method has the advantage of work in GTK3 and KDE applications. I could recommend to unfold the "Key to show the 3rd level" section and select the "Right Alt; Shift+Right Alt as Compose" option instead of use CapsLock and no longer have the normal function of that key.

Answer (score 0):

I observed that Ctrl+Shift+u followed by a specific numeric works in Kate and Konsole version 21.08.2.

Crtl+Shift+U+2665 = ♥

Comment: Please edit and clarify: `doesn't work at all in Kate...` or `do work in Kate....`? As it is currently written it looks like a typo. In English  **at all**, after a verb, is usually used as a *negative emphasis*. So, your answer appears to suggest that the key combination does **not** work... is that what you are trying to say?