# Greek accent not working in system, while working in some applications

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, 19.10

I'm on Kubuntu 19.10, installed recently.

While I can use the greek accent to accent vowels (example: **ά**) in applications like Firefox and Discord, I can't do the same in the file manager, text editor, or LibreOffice Writer, to name a few.

Instead, when I press **accent** + **vowel**, I get nothing. But if I press **accent** twice, I get only the accent itself, which is expected behavior. The problem is the same for all accent/ vowel combinations.

My layout is **Greek** with variant **Greek (simple)**, but since I can accent vowels correctly in Firefox, the layout isn't the issue. Before Kubuntu I was on the latest Linux Mint, and while using the same layout I didn't have this issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you read this here ? :  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language-install.html.en

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and I have three keyboards (**Input Sources**  in **Region & Language** of `gnome-control-center`): English, Turkish, and Greek. I can type Greek accented letters in `gedit`, `firefox`, or LibreOffice when l switch to Greek keyboard with no problem: ά, έ, ί, ή, ό, ώ, Ά, Έ, Ί, Ή, Ό, Ώ. By the way, my System **Language** is **English (United States)** and my **Formats** is **United Kingdom**.

Comment: I can type baria, dasia, psili and all variations also: Ἁἁἅἀἄᾳᾰᾱᾶϊ using the relevant ALT GR key combinations.

Comment: @dschinn1001 The settings in KDE are a little different, but yes, I have tried adding Greek in that menu, and even set it as default, rebooted, and had no different result. In any case, as I understand that is used to set the system language, which is different from setting the input language. Normally my system language is set to American English but I have American English and Greek as input languages.

Comment: **Important note: I am using the "Greek" keyboard and NOT the "Greek (simple)" keyboard!** For alpha with oxia, I switch to Greek keyboard and I press "ALT GR" + "the key to the right of the letter L", release both keys and then press "letter A" key: ά. Pressing simply the key to right of "L" (with no ALT GR) also works...

Comment: As another example: To type ᾆ you press ALT GR + "the letter to the right of P", release both keys, press ALT GR + "the letter to the second right of P", release both keys,  press ALT GR + SHIFT + "the letter to the right of L", release three keys, and press "A". However, these do ***not*** work in "Greek (simple)".

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I'm sorry but you're not helping. I'm not using the **polytonic** variant. The **simple** variant includes the common accent, and it's the keyboard layout I've used in every Linux distribution with no problems so far. To accent a vowel I just have to press `;` + `α` = `ά`.

Comment: The problem maybe with only with `qt` applications which is a long-lasting problem.

Comment: @DKBose How do I make sure? Although as I said above, I had no problem with accents in Linux Mint, even in LibreOffice.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you use the "Greek (polytonic)" variant (I haven't used it either). I am suggesting you try the "Greek" keyboard (which is the one I have used so far in my examples), instead of the "Greek (simple)" variant.

Comment: Firefox is a gtk app and works for you. The file manager, Dolphin, is `qt`. The text editor, Kate is `qt`. And if you have `libreoffice-qt5` your libreoffice will also be affected.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I've tried all variants, same problem.

Comment: @DKBose alright, makes perfect sense (I do have `libreoffice-qt5` installed). So as far as you know, there's no known solution to this?

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095339/how-can-i-input-unicode-characters-in-kate-and-konsole-on-kubuntu-18-04 and https://superuser.com/a/493243/462117 help.

Comment: For libreoffice, you could `sudo apt purge libreoffice-qt5` and `sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3`.

Comment: @DKBose The file manager and the text editor were my main concerns, but I don't want to download different packages for everything. Thanks a lot for providing me with the links though, and for your help in general.

Comment: Sorry for ressurecting this, but I have exactly the same problem and can't find the solution anywhere. Does anybody know how to fix it?